# how can I run a command from an environment variable and have the internal trailing ampersand work?

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable, background-process, job-control

I have this small script I call `prompt-to-run`.

```
prompt_acc=''

read -p 'run `'"$1"'`
' -i "$1" -e prompt_acc

$prompt_acc
```

It lets me create a script that fills in a command for me, but gives me the chance to edit or skip running it without stopping the whole script.

I have a different script, which we can call `long-running-script` I want to run that I want to run in its own terminal, since after taking some input it sits there and outputs more text continuously. I want to be able to start running it from a script containing several `prompt-to-run` invocations, and then get back my original terminal so I can run the next `prompt-to-run` invocation.

I've made `long-running-script` internally open a new terminal, so manually typing out

```
long-running-script &
```

starts up the program I want to run and gives me back my prompt in the original terminal. But `prompt-to-run 'long-running-script &'` doesn't return the terminal prompt. I suppose this is because the command is being run from inside an environment variable, `$prompt_acc`, so it's not being interpreted the way I want.

Is there a way to change one or both of `prompt-to-run` or `long-running-script` to get what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only processing done on the expansion of a variable is word splitting and wildcard expansion. Other shell metacharacters are ignored.

If you want the contents of the variable to be executed as if you'd typed the command, use the `eval` command:

```
eval "$prompt_acc"
```

This will perform all normal shell processing of the command, including quote processing, executing multiple commands separated by `;`, backgrounding with `&`, I/O redirection, etc.

BTW, `prompt_acc` is just an ordinary shell variable, it's not an environment variable. The `export` command is the way to put variables into the environment.

Comment: Ah! Even better, since this way the displayed command will just work if I copy paste into another terminal.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, the reason is since it is being run from inside an environment variable.  Therefore, the entire subsequent text, including the `&`, is being passed as an argument to your `long-running-script`.

The way around that is, to have the invocation `$prompt_acc &` instead of `$prompt_acc` in your `prompt-to-run` file.  This way, if you decide you don't want to run the script, the `&` does not get in the way.

Comment: This works perfectly. I've made a new script called `prompt-to-run-in-background` with this change so now I can decide on a command by command basis whether it should be in the background or not.